# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied when trying to play mp3 with python

Tags: python, pydub

I'm trying to play an mp3 with pydub, and I keep getting the error

```
  File "c:\Users\ryanc\Desktop\codefiles\python\audio player.py", line 5, in <module>
    play(song)
  File "C:\Users\ryanc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\playback.py", line 71, in play
    _play_with_ffplay(audio_segment)
  File "C:\Users\ryanc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\playback.py", line 15, in _play_with_ffplay
    seg.export(f.name, "wav")
  File "C:\Users\ryanc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 867, in export
    out_f, _ = _fd_or_path_or_tempfile(out_f, 'wb+')
  File "C:\Users\ryanc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 60, in _fd_or_path_or_tempfile
    fd = open(fd, mode=mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\ryanc\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpkdgigv5o.wav'
```

My code is just

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

song = AudioSegment.from_file("C:\\Users\\ryanc\\Music\\rr.mp3")
play(song)
```

I tried running vscode with admin but that didnt work either.

Comment: Could be incorrect file path. You're using double slashes in your path, is that intentional?

Comment: @Jab Windows backslashes in filenames *have* to be escaped because \ is a metacharacter in Python strings. OP is correctly avoiding a common novice error.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems that 'pydub' library by default is not able to play .mp3 songs. You will neeed to convert it into .wav format and then execute the command again.

So here is your code with some minor modifications:

```py
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

song = AudioSegment.from_mp3("C:\\Users\\ryanc\\Music\\rr.mp3")
play(song)
```

Now in order to work for this you need to have the ffmpeg installed. If not it will gain throw an error. [Download ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and paste the code to your script directory.

Here is the [link](https://dev.to/mathewthe2/playing-mp3-files-in-python-with-pydub-and-pyaudio-579i) to make you better understand the process.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but that just gave me another error. basically a bunch of failed conversions.

```Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input

[mp3float @ 00000203591b4d80] Header missing
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
size=       2kB time=00:00:00.02 bitrate= 729.5kbits/s speed=0.412x
video:0kB audio:2kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 3.385417%
Conversion failed!``

Comment: Can you try converting your .mp3 file to .wav file using the following chunk of code?
```ffmpeg -i rr.mp3 rr.wav``` and then use that file to play the song. This will do.

Comment: this worked for me, but thanks anyway!

```from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
 

tape = AudioSegment.from_file(r'C:\Users\ryanc\Music\rr.mp3')
 
play(tape)```

Answer (score 1):

Try this link..

https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/209

Adding f.close() line in playback.py to close the stream works magic.

```
def _play_with_ffplay(seg):
with NamedTemporaryFile("w+b", suffix=".wav") as f:
    f.close() # close the file stream
    seg.export(f.name, "wav")
    subprocess.call([PLAYER, "-nodisp", "-autoexit", "-hide_banner", f.name])
```

Comment: The linked issue is marked as closed, but the bug fix was not published. This oneliner worked for me (Win11)

Answer (score 0):

If saving the mp3 to a file isn't a pain for you, then using the audio playback extension is the easiest option.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=sukumo28.wav-preview

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to install pyAudio from python package

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by installing this library

```
pip install pyAudio
```

Comment: This answer appears to be a duplicate of the answer provided by @Negm Eldeen on 22nd Dec 2022