# PyDub: ffmpeg not found

Tags: python, pydub, ffmpeg-python, permissionerror

I have pip installed python-ffmpeg and am trying to play a wav file with PyDub. I get this warning:

```
   Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\divel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pydub\utils.py", line 170
    warn("Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work", RuntimeWarning)
RuntimeWarning: Couldn't find ffmpeg or avconv - defaulting to ffmpeg, but may not work
```

And then a permission error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\divel\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp0t700dh0.wav'
```

Any suggestions on how to fix it?
The code itself is:

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play

snippet = AudioSegment.from_file('suoni\snippet6.wav', format = 'wav')
play(snippet)
```

Comment: Refer to this question on how to specify the ffmpeg path: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284461/pydub-windowserror-error-2-the-system-can-not-find-the-file-specified/24354699#24354699
About the permission problem: you have to run your Python program as user `divel` or as administrator in order to have to permissions to modify this temporary folder.

Comment: Thank you. I have installed ffmpeg in C and set the path to it. I have tried both ```AudioSegment.ffmpeg = "/C/ffmpeg"``` and
```AudioSegment.converter = "/C/ffmpeg''``` but to no avail: the same error persits. I am running this in IDLE but I don't understand how can I run it as administrator. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Try this answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73601217/19808651) It solves the permission error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your operating system is Windows. In this case you should specify the location where you installed `ffmpeg` using the class attribute `AudioSegment.converter` and one of the following path syntax variants:

```
AudioSegment.converter = 'C:/ffmpeg'
AudioSegment.converter = 'C:\\ffmpeg'
```

Note the double backslash in the second path, as backslashes are used as escape characters, so backslashes have to be escaped with a backslash ;)

You could try right-clicking the IDLE link or the IDLE executable (`.exe`) and then choosing *Run as Administrator* to solve the permission issue.

Comment: Sorry for not having specified this beforehand, I am indeed operating on Windows. I have tried both solutions and they don't work. It's quite frustrating because I tried to use PyDub on LinuxMint and it works like a charm...

Comment: Hmm...have you actually installed ffmpeg at `C:\ffmpeg` or maybe another location like `C:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg`? Also check the exact spelling regarding upper and lowercase letters. In fact it's best to copy the exact path from the Windows Explorer. Please also try the `bin` folder or even the complete path to ffmpeg.exe, e.g. `C:\ffmpeg\bin` and `C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe`.

Comment: I tried it all, also while running Python as administrator: still stuck with Errno 13. Thank youvery much for your help, this is becoming unnerving.

Comment: I noticed that you use a path with a single slash in the `AudioSegment.from_file()` call. Try replacing `suoni\snippet6.wav` with `suoni\\snippet6.wav` or `suoni/snippet6.wav`. Alternatively you could try using an absolute path like `C:\\Users\\whatever\\path\\snippet6.wav`. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you again. I tried all the possible different combinations but it still isn't working.